# Intervention Image processing much slower on apache server than built in php server

Tags: php, apache, performance, laravel, intervention

I am using Intervention Image throughout my Laravel application, for example with loading thumbnails for each 'item'. On my laptop for testing I am using the built in php server and the TTFB is about half a second for each photo, which isn't insanely fast but it is adequate. However, after deploying it to my vps running apache, the TTFB for each photo is now over 20 seconds when multiple images are loaded,  which obviously is way to long. This is the code which takes so long:

```
return Image::make(imagecreatefromjpeg($img_path))->resize(null, $thumbnail_width, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
```

Should my vps be slowed down so much for multiple requests? As it takes about 1 second for one image but about 20 for each image when there is ten. 
Thanks!

Comment: There are so many possible reasons, I am afraid this question in its current form is Off Topic

Comment: I have updated the question as I have realised it is only when multiple images are loaded at once

Comment: How large are the files? localy its fast because its  basicly copyingon the same hd. server may also have limits for speed etc

Comment: @SvenB each file is about 3-4mb. It's a digitalocean vps so it has an SSD.